# CMake stdlib include issue

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

I need to compile a C++ project using CMake and MinGW-w64. The project depends on zlib, so CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
```

CMake will fail on ZLIB unless I add the following path to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:

```
C:/Dev/mingw64-8.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
```

With this path added, CMake runs fine. But, I get the following compile error:

```
#include_next <stdlib.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:/Dev/mingw64-8.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/cstdlib:75:15:
fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
```

After some search about this last error, I found I can fix it by editing the CMake includes_CXX.rsp and either:

- Remove `-isystem C:/Dev/mingw64-8.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include`
- Or change `-isystem` to `-I`

So basically I have to pass the include path to CMake so that it finds zlib.h, and remove this path from the files generated by CMake... Is there a proper solution?

Thanks!